# Why does `gtk_builder_add_objects` tell me "Object with ID saveas_csv not found" when adding to the glade XML?

Tags: xml, gtk3, gnome, glade

I'm trying to add a menu item to [xnec2c](https://www.xnec2c.org/) by modifying its .glade file.  The issue as described below generates the error `.:9653:53 Object with ID saveas_csv not found`.  If I remove the `<property name="image">saveas_csv</property>` tag then it works, but the menu then item has no icon image.  I would like to have the image icon be the same as the one for `saveas_gnuplot` as described below:

I've copy-pasted these as a starting point (links will take you to the .glade lines on github):

[xnec2c.glade#L9537:](https://github.com/KJ7LNW/xnec2c/blob/master/resources/xnec2c.glade#L9537)

```xml
<object class="GtkImage" id="saveas_gnuplot">
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="can-focus">False</property>
  <property name="stock">gtk-save-as</property>
</object>
```

[xnec2c.glade#L9632:](https://github.com/KJ7LNW/xnec2c/blob/master/resources/xnec2c.glade#L9632)

```xml
<child>                                                                                   
  <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="freqplots_save_as_gnuplot">                        
    <property name="label" translatable="yes">Save as _gnuplot</property>                 
    <property name="visible">True</property>                                              
    <property name="can-focus">False</property>                                           
    <property name="use-underline">True</property>                                        
    <property name="image">saveas_gnuplot</property>                                      
    <property name="use-stock">False</property>                                           
    <signal name="activate" handler="on_freqplots_save_as_gnuplot_activate" swapped="no"/>
  </object>                                                                               
</child>                                                                                  
<child>
```

After copy-pasting just below each example above, I changed the ID's and changed the image property in the new GtkImageMenuItem to match as follows. Note that the only change were ids `saveas_gnuplot` to `saveas_csv`, and id+handlers `*save_as_gnuplot*` to `*save_as_csv*`:

```xml
<object class="GtkImage" id="saveas_csv">
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="can-focus">False</property>
  <property name="stock">gtk-save-as</property>
</object>
```

```xml
<child>
  <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="freqplots_save_as_csv">
    <property name="label" translatable="yes">Save as _CSV</property>
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
    <property name="use-underline">True</property>
    <property name="image">saveas_csv</property>
    <property name="use-stock">False</property>
    <signal name="activate" handler="on_freqplots_save_as_csv_activate" swapped="no"/>
  </object>
</child>
```

The `saveas_gnuplot` ID does show up in two other places in the .glade file, but they are just  image references in other GTK windows so I don't think that is the issue:

- https://github.com/KJ7LNW/xnec2c/blob/master/resources/xnec2c.glade#L10431
- https://github.com/KJ7LNW/xnec2c/blob/master/resources/xnec2c.glade#L11577

Not sure if it is useful, but this is [how the application loads the .glade file](https://github.com/KJ7LNW/xnec2c/blob/master/src/interface.c#L28):

```c
/* Create a builder from object ids */
*builder = gtk_builder_new();
ret = (int)gtk_builder_add_objects_from_resource(
    *builder, "/xnec2c.glade", object_ids, &gerror );
if( !ret )
{
  pr_err("failed to add objects to builder: %s\n", gerror->message);
  ...
}
```

and here is the debug output listing IDs that were loaded. As you can see, `saveas_csv` is not listed:

```c
[16410 err:Gtk_Builder] interface.c:39: failed to add objects to builder: .:9668:53 Object with ID saveas_csv not found
[16410 err:Gtk_Builder] interface.c:41: Listing Object Ids:
[16410 err:Gtk_Builder] interface.c:45: freqplots_zo_adjustment
[16410 err:Gtk_Builder] interface.c:45: freqplots_window
[16410 err:Gtk_Builder] interface.c:45: freqplots_box
[16410 err:Gtk_Builder] interface.c:45: saveas_gnuplot
[16410 err:Gtk_Builder] interface.c:45: freqplots_nec2_edit
[16410 err:Gtk_Builder] interface.c:45: freqplots_fmhz_entry
[16410 err:Gtk_Builder] interface.c:45: freqplots_maxgain_entry
[16410 err:Gtk_Builder] interface.c:45: freqplots_vswr_entry
[16410 err:Gtk_Builder] interface.c:45: freqplots_zreal_entry
[16410 err:Gtk_Builder] interface.c:45: freqplots_zimag_entry
[16410 err:Gtk_Builder] interface.c:45: freqplots_zo_spinbutton
[16410 err:Gtk_Builder] interface.c:45: freqplots_drawingarea
[16410 err:Gtk_Builder] interface.c:45: freqplots_label
[16410 err:Gtk_Builder] interface.c:45: freqplots_net_gain
```

This is the diff against the .glade file if you would like to try it:

```
diff --git a/resources/xnec2c.glade b/resources/xnec2c.glade
index 363167e..fefc806 100644
--- a/resources/xnec2c.glade
+++ b/resources/xnec2c.glade
@@ -9539,6 +9539,11 @@ Save NEC2 Editor data first?
     <property name="can-focus">False</property>
     <property name="stock">gtk-save-as</property>
   </object>
+  <object class="GtkImage" id="saveas_csv">
+    <property name="visible">True</property>
+    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
+    <property name="stock">gtk-save-as</property>
+  </object>
   <object class="GtkWindow" id="freqplots_window">
     <property name="visible">True</property>
     <property name="can-focus">False</property>
@@ -9640,6 +9645,17 @@ Save NEC2 Editor data first?
                           </object>
                         </child>
                         <child>
+                          <object class="GtkImageMenuItem" id="freqplots_save_as_csv">
+                            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Save as _CSV</property>
+                            <property name="visible">True</property>
+                            <property name="can-focus">False</property>
+                            <property name="use-underline">True</property>
+                            <property name="image">saveas_csv</property>
+                            <property name="use-stock">False</property>
+                            <signal name="activate" handler="on_freqplots_save_as_csv_activate" swapped="no"/>
+                          </object>
+                        </child>
+                        <child>
                           <object class="GtkMenuItem" id="freqplots_touchstone_menu">
                             <property name="visible">True</property>
                             <property name="can-focus">False</property>
```

Comment: Did you change some file in wrong folder? Seems that `saveas_gnuplot` is still there and not renamed.

Comment: @Gerhardh, see the diff at the bottom of the post.  That looks right...